Specific sqlite3odbs.Dll path connectionString sqlite
is there a way to add a specific Dll path in a connectionString for Sqlite and VBA.
indead i'm working on win10 without admin privelege to install dlls; i downloaded the dlls and put them into a personal folder.
then i need to create a ConnectionString that seek on those folders
i tried ResolutionPath, PathExt but nojn of those solutios works with me

Assuming you have registered the DLLs you could try adding the folder in which they are located to the Environment variable PATH - add it near to the front to ensure this path takes precedence over any other copies
